# kotlinx de/serialization sealed class/enum

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

Writing chat app using kotlin,
historically from nodejs I have websocket json objects in/output format:

```
{"action": "join:chatroom", "payload", "chatroom-name"}
{"action": "leave:chatroom", "payload", "chatroom-name"}
{"action": "message", "payload", {"id": 1, "text": "blah", "user": {"name": "Roman"}}}
{"action": "notification", "payload", {"id": 1, "verb": "blah", "user": {"name": "Roman"}}}
```

trying to adopt kotlinx serialization to be able to work with this type of approach with no luck
seems like `sealed class` is the closest what I can try but how to change `type` to `action`

took this approach
https://ahsensaeed.com/sealed-classes-kotlinx-serialization-deserialization/
trying to do something like:

```kotlin
@Polymorphic
@Serializable
sealed class BackendAction{
    @Serializable
    data class Auth(
//        val action: String = "authorize",
        val payload: String = ""
    ) : BackendAction()
}

class BackendActionSerializer {
    private val sealedModule = SerializersModule {
        polymorphic(BackendAction::class) {
            BackendAction.Auth::class with BackendAction.Auth.serializer()
        }
    }

    private val serializer: KSerializer<BackendAction>
        get() = BackendAction.serializer()

    val format: StringFormat
        get() = Json(configuration = JsonConfiguration(classDiscriminator = "action"), context = sealedModule)

    fun toStringT(json: String): BackendAction {
        return format.parse(serializer, json)
    }

    fun toTString(t: BackendAction): String {
        return format.stringify(serializer, t)
    }
}
```

and call:

```
    val act = BackendAction.Auth("blah")
    val serializer = BackendActionSerializer()
    val data = serializer.toTString(act)
```

gives `{"action":"com.project.path.BackendAction.Auth","payload":"blah"}`
so I need mapping `com.project.path.BackendAction.Auth` to `authorize`

**EDIT:**

answering my question:
`@SerialName("authorize")`
it was easy :)

```
@Polymorphic
@Serializable
sealed class BackendAction{
    @Serializable
    @SerialName("authorize")
    data class Auth(
        var payload: String = ""
    ) : BackendAction()
}
```

working web ui for this chat app here:
https://www.lonje.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SerialName("authorize")` do the trick

```
@Polymorphic
@Serializable
sealed class BackendAction{
    @Serializable
    @SerialName("authorize")
    data class Auth(
        var payload: String = ""
    ) : BackendAction()
}
```